# Namespace path in WPF XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have Content directory in main solution.
In content catalog i have two catalogs: ViewModels and Views

In XAML, i have declared:

```
 xmlns:vm ="clr-namespace:AppName.Content"
```

now, i want get reference to some class in ViewModel catalog:

```
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:LaserPathViewModel}">
```

I know thats wrong because the namespace of LaserPathViewModel is AppName.Content.ViewModels.

But how get this reference without add next one namespace declaration?

Answer (score 0):

You don't. You have to declare that other namespace. One way to do that is by adding another namespace declaration:

```
xmlns:vm2 ="clr-namespace:AppName.Content.ViewModel"
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm2:LaserPathViewModel}">
```

But there is another way to declare the namespaces. You can use the [`XmlnsAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) which allows you to map multiple .NET namespaces to one X(A)ML namespace. You can find some nice explanation [here](http://zachbonham.blogspot.nl/2010/04/organize-xaml-namespace-declarations.html?m=1).